# Expression for contribution of demagnetizing field to magnetic field in long thin superconductor with long axes parallel to magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

I am reading Superconductors from Kittle's Introduction to Solid State Physics book, there while giving a brief idea about the Meissner effect, that superconductors behave as if $B=0$ inside and then the author mentions equations $(1)$ for limiting case, I am unable to understand how?
Even referring to chapter $16$, it's not clear how we got there, can anyone please explain?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a long and thin magnetizable material if the external bias field is parallel with the long axis of the rod then the *demagnetizing* field, that is the one induced by the end poles, is negligible because the ends (poles) are *small* relative to the rest of the rod. Therefore the total flux density is the applied flux density $B_a$ plus the induced magnetization $M$, that is equation I: $B=B_a+4\pi M$ but from Meissner we know that for superconducting material the total flux *inside* is zero, i.e, $B_a+4\pi M = 0$.